# Debian FIPS Certified

Tags: debian, cryptography

Is Debian OS FIPS certified? Does it support FIPS Validated Cryptographic Modules?

What I noticed is that FIPS mode can be enabled with the tool [fips-mode-setup](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/crypto-policies/fips-mode-setup.8.en.html). This tool is developed and can be used for other Linux distributions (SUSE, Oracle Linux, RedHat, Ubuntu), in case the user wants to enable FIPS mode afterwards (not part of OS). Does that mean that Debian can be configured to use FIPS Validated Cryptographic Modules?